# Oracle 10g Enterprise Edition Backup to .sql file

Tags: oracle10g

I have oracle 10g enterprise edition. I want to perform table backup and full database backup to .sql files to be able to move to another server/PC ...

If possible, image explanation ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move to a different **Oracle** server, you should use:

```
expdp
```

To export your data. And:

```
impdp
```

To import it on the other database. [Here's](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Data+Pump+Export+%28expdp%29+and+Data+Pump+Import%28impdp%29) a WIKI entry that might help you. It's the easy way of moving data around Oracle servers.

On the other hand, ff you want to move your data to a different DATABASE SERVER (not Oracle branded) you would need some sort of translator in the way.

Comment: Yes. Windows XP, Linux, Unix, any platform where you can install Oracle 10g, you can run `impdp` and `expdp`. It's bundled with the server.

Comment: from where can I use this cmd?

Comment: [Easy Dump Oracle](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/Easy-Dump-Oracle.shtml) is a simple GUI frontend to the `exp`/`imp` commands